# What are the best characters to use for placeholders in file names (on Windows) AND URLs?

Tags: c#, url, filenames, placeholder

I am writing an application in C# that will need to find placeholders in URLs and/or filenames, and substitute in a value, much like this: `C:\files\file{number}` => `C:\files\file1` Unfortunately for that example, curly braces are allowed in file names and URLs.

Can anyone please suggest some characters that I can use to denote placeholders in files and URLs? Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to pay attention to other operating systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows rather helpfully tells you what characters aren't allowed in a filename, when you try to use on of them:

> A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
>    \ / : * ? " < > |

See [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506) for more information, including the list of **allowed** characters.

> Characters that are valid for naming
>   files, folders, or shortcuts include
>   any combination of letters (A-Z) and
>   numbers (0-9), plus the following
>   special characters:

```
^   Accent circumflex (caret)
&   Ampersand
'   Apostrophe (single quotation mark)
@   At sign
{   Brace left
}   Brace right
[   Bracket opening
]   Bracket closing
,   Comma
$   Dollar sign
=   Equal sign
!   Exclamation point
-   Hyphen
#   Number sign
(   Parenthesis opening
)   Parenthesis closing
%   Percent
.   Period
+   Plus
~   Tilde
_   Underscore
```

As for URLs, see section 2.2 of [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for a description of allowed characters:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the
>   special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and 
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

...also of interest, from the same section:

> Characters can be unsafe for a number
>   of reasons.  The space character is
>   unsafe because significant spaces may
>   disappear and insignificant spaces may
>   be introduced when URLs are
>   transcribed or typeset or subjected to
>   the treatment of word-processing
>   programs. The characters "<" and ">"
>   are unsafe because they are used as
>   the delimiters around URLs in free
>   text; the quote mark (""") is used to
>   delimit URLs in some systems.  The
>   character "#" is unsafe and should
>   always be encoded because it is used
>   in World Wide Web and in other systems
>   to delimit a URL from a
>   fragment/anchor identifier that might
>   follow it.  The character "%" is
>   unsafe because it is used for
>   encodings of other characters.  Other
>   characters are unsafe because gateways
>   and other transport agents are known
>   to sometimes modify such characters.
>   These characters are "{", "}", "|",
>   "\", "^", "~", "[", "]", and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

It looks like the double-quote and angle bracket characters (`"<>`) are good options.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I need characters that are invalid in file names AND URLs, however.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that the double-quotation mark will work, then.